# How to fix the error cannot assing "xx" to type intrinstic attributes and props using react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am getting an error cannot find count and cannot assign {count: number; title:string} type to IntrinsicAttributes using react and typescript.

i have two components ParentComponent and ChildComponent

within parent component i am passing count prop to ChildComponent and the code is like below,

```
function ParentComponent = () => {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent count={5} title="sometitle"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


interface Props {
  count: number;
  title: string;
}
function ChildComponent = ({ count, title }: Props) => {
    render =() =>{
        return (
            <>
                <span>
                    {title}
                </span>
                <span>
                    {count}
                </span>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Could someone help me understand or fix this. thanks.

Comment: Does this help you?? https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-yonath-kp2pt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent count={5} title="sometitle" />
    </div>
  );
};

interface Props {
  count: number;
  title: string;
}
const ChildComponent = ({ count, title }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>{title}</span>
      <span>{count}</span>
    </>
  );
};
```

Notes:

- You can't use the `React.ClassComponent` method `render` in `React.FunctionComponents` (you simply `return` instead)
- You're mixing function syntax with arrow function syntax. I used the latter above.

Comment: thanks i tried your solution and its still throwing that error.

Comment: That's odd. Can you provide a sandbox for it?

Comment: It doesn't throw here https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCtCAOwGd4AFFImmAYV0hqTbgF44ACgCUAgHxwA3hThwiMAK5Qaw2XLgAeACbAAbuPUat7ABbAANts7haveNUVt+UgKwBfODGAwLSfgBEdLhI3r5IAXAA9IbkxppRugbqIgDcFO7plOTAbEhQmOhIcIw4YHTS6o5sAFxwNIogAEb5WXJhfnUMULkA5lnuFFS0DHBmltZcdnyCQlJw1TAANF4+fnDudaUQ5WL8kjJx8qHKqkJGWrHGcpp0YCg04lIdSO4Jdw9X17f3j1KLbyiH0eFwSXzSGVSQA